# Generating a random num from a triangular distribution

Tags: probability, triangles, random

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution#cite_note-1

under "Generating Triangular-distributed random variates" given that U is a number between 0 and 1, what happens if the a, b and c values are greater than 1? Does it change the conditions?

For example, how would the
0 < U < F (F is (c-a)/(b-a)) 
condition work for  a distribution where a = 10, b = 15 and c = 20, and where U was generated as 0.4?

Comment: Why exactly are you worried?

Comment: That in such a case the U will always be smaller than a, b and c. I'd think it needs to be transformed as some function of a, b and c before checking this condition.

Comment: $U$ is plugged in a function whose domain is $[0,1]$. This function is the inverse of the distribution function belonging to the triangle distribution. Take a closer look at the Wiki article.

Comment: Thanks for answering zoli, would you care to explain for example how the  0 < U < F (F is (c-a)/(b-a)) part works for, say, a distribution where a = 10, b = 15 and c = 20, and where U was generated as 0.4? Thanks again!

Comment: First of all improve your question by inserting your comments. Here your thought and efforts are important.

Comment: I have, i also understand that it's not the best question.

Comment: Why have you posted the same question twice, within minutes? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275428/generating-a-random-number-from-a-triangular-distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U$ be a random variable uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$. Also, let $F$ is the pdf of an arbitrary distribution. Denote the inverse of $F$ by $F^{-1}$. In our case $F$ is strictly monotonous over $[a,b]$

The first thing that you have to understand is that the random variable $Y=F^{-1}(U)$ will be distributed according to $F$:

$$F_Y(y)=P(Y<y)=P(F^{-1}(U)<y)=P(U<F(y))=F(y).$$

On Wiki you already found the distribution function of the triangular distribution. $U$ then is plugged in to the inverse of this distribution function, which is defined over $[0,1].$

Comment: Thank you again zoli, i've had a breakthrough and as i thought it was a simple misunderstanding of the math involved.